# search query results # still showing on new search (php)

Tags: php, refresh

$_SESSION are coming from another page.. when i run a search on my search engine the # of results shows up but stays on the page forever and ever.. have a look *(gawd i need 10 rep points to post images)*

well basically 0 results is always shown and below it are the results of the search which is always there as well.

---

**0 results for "pepsi" 

2 results for "flash"**

**flash - website tutorial

flash design - come learn from the best**

this is basically what the search page looks like only the search result links and descriptions will disappear if the search result produces no results. i would like to have **everything** disappear on every new search.. even when i refresh teh page or come back to it the results from the previous search are there.

```
     <div id="searchPageDiv">
    <?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){          
            echo $_SESSION['error'];

        } else      
            print_r($_SESSION['search_output']);        
        { 

            echo ($_SESSION['count']);
              foreach($_SESSION['search_output'] as $value){
                $value['links'];
                $value['title'];
                $value['page_body'];


                $title = $value['title'];
                $link = $value['links'];
                $body = $value['page_body'];

                $search_output .= "<a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a> - $body<br>";}
}
?>

    <?php echo $search_output; ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: You must unset the `$_SESSION` variable after echo.

Comment: ok thanks i guess i do some research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be helpful:

```
echo ($_SESSION['count']);
unset($_SESSION['count']);
```

Studying is best approach. Look for examples given in [www.php.net/unset](http://www.php.net/unset)